# How can summarize the elements number in row

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

### I have a xml file and i use xsl to tranform to html

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
    <student>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <class>1</class>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Jerry</name>
        <class>2</class>
    </student>
</list>
```

and this my XSL file, i show information "Name" and "Class" and show "Money" with condition in the template Money

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>TomJerryXSL.xsl</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table border="1" >
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Class</td>
                        <td>Money</td>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="/list/student">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="./name"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="./class"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:call-template name="money">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="class">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="./class"/>
                                    </xsl:with-param>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="money">
        <xsl:param name="class"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$class=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="100"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$class=2">
                <xsl:value-of select="200"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i want show Total 300

```
Name    Class   Money
Tom         1    100
Jerry       2   200
```

**How can I summarize money and show it in html**
Sorry beacause my English is not good

Comment: What you mean by summarize is unclear, sum ip up so you would have a third row that shows something like `Total     300`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="100*count(/list/student/class[.='1']) + 200*count(/list/student/class[.='2'])"/>
```